# On jQuery button click, reusing the element content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Auto flushing the text area content

I have two text area. On button click content from this text area get translated from Arabic to English or English to Arabic.

When I load the page and start with any one of them it works fine.

Problem:

1.) When I perform Arabic to English translation it does. Now if I enter text in english text area and try to convert into arabic. It does not work. I need to reload the page for this.

2.) When I load the page, with which ever english to arabic or arabic 2 english conversation I start, it allows that only. For opposite converstion I need to reload the page.

I tried with

`english.innerHTML = '';`

first making content `''`, but that also does not help.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
       </div>
           <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="row">

            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5%;">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                    Aabic : 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                    <textarea style="height:200px" id="arabic" type="text" class="form-control"></textarea>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                            <a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success" id="ar2en" href=""> Ar to En </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
       </div>
           <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5%;">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                    English : 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                    <textarea style="height:200px"  id="english" type="text" class="form-control"></textarea>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                            <a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success" id="en2ar" href=""> En to Ar </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
       </div>
        <div class="show" id="show"></div>
        </div>
     </div>    
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script>
    $( "#ar2en" ).click(function() {
            //var cat = $("#cats option:selected").html();
//          alert(test);
            var arabic = document.getElementById("arabic").value;
            //alert (arabic)
            ar2en(arabic);
            return false;
            });
        function ar2en(arabic)
        {               
            var xmlhttp;
            english.innerHTML = '';
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }           
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                //document.getElementById("old-records").innerHTML = "";                
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var div2 = document.getElementById("english");
                                div2.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","processAra.php");              
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send('arabic=' + arabic + '&type=' + 'ar' ) ;           
            //alert(arabic);
        }               
// -----------
    $( "#en2ar" ).click(function() {
            //var cat = $("#cats option:selected").html();
//          alert(test);
            var english = document.getElementById("english").value;
            //alert (arabic)
            en2ar(english);
            return false;
            });
        function en2ar(english)
        {               
            var xmlhttp;
            arabic.innerHTML = '';
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }           
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                //document.getElementById("old-records").innerHTML = "";                
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var div2 = document.getElementById("arabic");
                                div2.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","processAra.php");              
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send('arabic=' + english + '&type=' + 'en' ) ;          
            //alert(arabic);
        }               
    </script>
```

UPDATE:

```
$( "#ar2en" ).click(function() {
        $('#english').val("");
        //var arabic = document.getElementById("arabic").value;
        ar2en(arabic);
        return false;
        });
```

Comment: Try using if statement to check which of the two has a value. Then whichever of them has value then the translation only works for that value.

Comment: @jacelysh: this did not help. Even though it has value, it does not translate without reloading the page

Comment: I tested you code without "bootstrapp" - btw. did you work under twitter-bootstrap? - and it work did with `.value`

Comment: @reporter: yes, it worked with `.value`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `value` instead of `innerHTML` for fields.

A `textarea` may have content as a tag, but this content becomes its value.

Comment: It exists a simpler explanation: A textarea is an element of a form. And form fields having a value.

Comment: @Lucas: thanks but using `english.value = ''` stops giving any of the result

Comment: @reporter: I used `arabic.value = '';` afer  `<textarea style="height:200px" id="arabic" name = "arabic" type="text" class="form-control"></textarea>                           ` but no help

Comment: @user3449212 that's because you've defined `arabic` as a string: `var arabic = document.getElementById("arabic").value;`. Define it as a field instead: `var arabic = document.getElementById("arabic")` and change the usages.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: thanks. Initially I did same, but that does not help me. If I dont use `.value` then `var arabic = document.getElementById("arabic");` gives me ` [object HTMLTextAreaElement]`

Comment: @reporter: can you please see my last comment